# How to open new javafx fxml window under if condtition?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, view-helpers

I create a simple login form to checking username and password. 
I did it and my problem is while checking the username and password is correct open new fxml window. 
Can anyone drop some simple code to solve it.

Comment: "Any one drop simple code for solve it". That's not how Stack Overflow works. You shouldn't just dump some requirements and ask nicely for us to do it for you. You *can* but we won't. We will help you with code you've written, we will explain why it doesn't work, we will not write it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, below is just an example to get you started but what I usually do is I create some sort of a stage factory so that I don't have a lot of duplicate code. 
Let me know if you have any questions.

My example:

```
if(/*your if condition*/){
    YourController controller = new YourController();
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(fxmlPath));
    loader.setController(controller);
    Parent root = loader.load();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, width, height, Color.WHITE);
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    stage.setX(xPos);
    stage.setY(yPos);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

Edit, I felt nice today but I do agree with the first comment that you received. Remember to read through the guide lines next time.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I am beginner for coding so I face lot's of struggles. Your comments are very helpful for me..

Comment: I'm glad that I was able to help. Don't hesitate to post more questions if you can't find an answer after searching for it here. Just read through the guide lines first :)  Have a good day and good luck with the coding!